# RecyclerView Laggy Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a recyclerview with a list of burned data but when testing, both the scroll and the entire screen is laggy too much, I already tried not to fill the list and the screen works well but I have another screen where I also fill an equal list that in this and with even more things in the layout and it gives me no problem.

here is my code:

```
TextView txtToolbar;
RecyclerView list_comercio;
ComercioAdapter comercioAdapter;
List<Comercio> comercioList;

String categoria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comercio);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
    Window window = ComercioActivity.this.getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    categoria = getIntent().getStringExtra("cat");

    txtToolbar = findViewById(R.id.txtToolbar);
    txtToolbar.setText(categoria);

    list_comercio   = findViewById(R.id.listComercios);

    comercioList = new ArrayList<>();


    comercioList.add(new Comercio(0, "Odontología", R.drawable.dent));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(1,"Fútbol", R.drawable.futbol));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(2, "Peluquería", R.drawable.peluqueria));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(3, "Peluquería", R.drawable.peluqueria));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(4, "Peluquería", R.drawable.peluqueria));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(5, "Peluquería", R.drawable.peluqueria));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(6, "Peluquería", R.drawable.peluqueria));
    comercioList.add(new Comercio(7, "Peluquería", R.drawable.peluqueria));

    list_comercio.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list_comercio.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    comercioAdapter = new ComercioAdapter(this, comercioList, this);
    list_comercio.setAdapter(comercioAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Have you put `RecyclerView ` inside `ScrollView`? If so, use `NestedScrollView` and mark `setNestedScrollingEnabled = false` for `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Ty!, if u want put in as an Answer to give you the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`, Use `NestedScrollView` and mark `setNestedScrollingEnabled = false` for `RecyclerView`.